# Pass related node into view

Tags: views, nodes

I have two kind of nodes Person and Survey. Unintuitively and for historic reasons, a Survey can be attached to more than one person, but a person only has one survey.

When a person node is displayed, the survey is embedded via a view.

I need to display that person's name in the survey view, however all attempts to find the person from the survey view result in a list of all people related, not necessarily the particular one being shown now.

How do I make the name of the specific person who were looking at available to the view?

So, eg if I go to http://example.com/person/Bob

```
Bob's details
Bob's survey
  Survey field 1
  Bob's name <--- How do i do this?
  Survey field 2
```

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Is `Bob's name` something that's going to change based on an answer submitted by Bob? Or are you trying to just duplicate the same value (`Bob`) that's at the top?

Comment: No, that's the challenge - Bob's name is part of the Person node, not part of the Survey node, but i need that field available in the survey view.
(I'm not actually displaying the name, but need it for the HTML markup. The example above is simplified)